# Multiple HTTPS Endpoints for Azure Cloud Service

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, azure-cloud-services

I have an Azure cloud service with 2 web roles. Using the configuration below, I can connect to site 1 via http and https, but only via http with site 2. Is there anything obvious I have missed here?

```
Site 1
<Sites>
  <Site name="Web">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
      <Binding name="HttpsIn" endpointName="HttpsIn" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
  <InputEndpoint name="HttpsIn" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="mycert" />
</Endpoints>
<Certificates>
  <Certificate name="mycert" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="CA" />
</Certificates>

Site2
<Sites>
  <Site name="Web">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
      <Binding name="HttpsIn" endpointName="HttpsIn" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="8081" />
  <InputEndpoint name="HttpsIn" protocol="https" port="445" certificate="mycert" />
</Endpoints>
<Certificates>
  <Certificate name="mycert" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="CA" />
</Certificates>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using a different port for site 2's https endpoint. It seems Azure Cloud Service didn't like port 445.